# Emulator issue, Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to run an app on my AVD but this errors show up
in the event Log and as a result my avd doesn't want to come out

```
Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so

Emulator: libGL error: driver pointer missing

Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: i965

Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so

Emulator: libGL error: driver pointer missing

Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: i965

Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so

Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast    

Emulator: X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)

Emulator: Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)

Emulator: Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)

Emulator: Value in failed request:  0x0

Emulator: Serial number of failed request:  64

Emulator: Current serial number in output stream:  65

Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867081/android-studio-buggy-after-upgrade-to-16-10).

Comment: Already tried that but it doesnt work for me.

Comment: Create a new emulator.